# Sort array of views on their y origin

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an IBCollections of Labels

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *titleLabel;
```

I'm asking myself if I could order those based on their `origin.y`, because they are basically vertically displayed one after one. Do you think it's possible, if yes how should I process to order the array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the array using a comparator block:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [titleLabel sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(UILabel *obj1, UILabel *obj2) {
    if ([obj1 frame].origin.y > [obj2 frame].origin.y) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else if ([obj1 frame].origin.y < [obj2 frame].origin.y) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

You can find more information in the [NSArray class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator:).

Answer (score 0):

You can add your labels to an NSDictionary and set the key to the y value casted to NSString. Then you get the values of the NSDictionary and bingo :)